# how to add a key word beside a paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs, keywords

I would like to add a key word beside a paragraph for the sake of clarity as follows

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

How can I fulfill this goal?

Comment: Should it always be on the same side (to the left)? Do you have a preference in terms of the interface?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}

\marginnote{\textcolor{red}{\small Key note}}\blindtext

\end{document}`

Comment: Yes. This key word sums up the paragraph. No preference just bold font.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thank you. I would accept it if you post it as an answer. How to control the distance? It is very close to the paragraph.

Comment: @CroCo Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is yo use `\marginnote` from the [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package; using the geometry package you can change `marginparsep` (the separation between the marginal note and the regular text) and/or `marginparwidth` the width reserved for the note:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[marginparsep=25pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\newcommand\KeyWord[1]{%
  \marginnote{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright\small \textcolor{red}{#1}}}}
\reversemarginpar 

\begin{document} 

\KeyWord{Key note}\blindtext 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just add it. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\KW}[1]{%
  \par % ensure vertical mode
  \leavevmode % start a paragraph
  {\setbox0=\lastbox}% remove the indentation box
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{#1}\hspace{2em}}% print the keyword
  \hspace*{\parindent}% add the parindent
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

This paragraph has no keyword, it has some boring text just to
make it wrap across a couple of lines.

\KW{key word}
This paragraph has a keyword, it has some boring text just to
make it wrap across a couple of lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a key-value interface which allows you to adjust the `sep`aration, the `font` and `color`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{KW}{sep}{}
\define@cmdkey{KW}{color}{}
\define@cmdkey{KW}{font}{}
\newcommand{\KeyWord}[2][]{%
  \par\noindent
  \setkeys{KW}{#1}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\textcolor{\cmdKV@KW@color}{\cmdKV@KW@font #2}\hspace*{\cmdKV@KW@sep}}%
  \hspace*{\parindent}\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\KeyWordsetup}[1]{\setkeys{KW}{#1}}%
\AtBeginDocument{\KeyWordsetup{font=\bfseries,color=red,sep=\marginparsep}}% defaults

\begin{document}

\KeyWord{Key note}\lipsum[1]

\KeyWord[sep=20pt]{Key Note}\lipsum[2]

\KeyWord[font=\itshape,color=blue!50]{KEY NOTE}\lipsum[3]

\KeyWordsetup{font=\slshape,color=red,sep=\marginparsep}%
\KeyWord{Key note}\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```